# For positive integers $a >b$ and positive real numbers $\alpha > \beta$, is it true $a^\alpha - a^\beta > b^\alpha - b^\beta$?

Tags: inequality, integers

Suppose I have positive integers $a >b$ and positive real numbers $\alpha > \beta$, is it true that $$a^\alpha - a^\beta > b^\alpha - b^\beta?$$

I can't seem to find a counterexample.

Comment: This is probably an off-topic answer given the "precalculus" tag, but it can be proved by noting if $f(x) = x^\alpha - x^\beta$, then $f'(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1} - \beta x^{\beta-1} = x^{\beta-1} (\alpha x^{\alpha - \beta} - \beta) > 0$ for $x > 1$.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler Thanks!